# System.Linq.Dynamic dynamic column name and parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am new to LINQ. I need to perform dynamic operations which seems to be done either with expression trees, or dynamic library. I chose to use System.Linq.Dynamic  since it is faster(at this point). I looked up around but nothing seems to help address my issue. I saw several stack post on the same issue but even after changing my code to that it still not resolved.

I am passing two strings(column name, search parameter) to my controller which will execute query and return JSON object. Column name and search parameters have to be dynamic.

```
The SQL query i need to execute: 
SELECT top 50 c1, c2, c3 
FROM TableName
WHERE column_name LIKE '%search_parameter%';


var result = db.TableName
   .Where("@0.Contains(@1)", column_name, search_parameter)
   .Select("new(c1, c2, c3.)");
```

For now i just want to select select those specific columns ill worry about top 50 later.

I tried also reading through examples on System.Linq.Dynamic but i think i am lacking the basic knowledge i need to understand a lot of the content. I would appreciate some pointers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For LIKE you can use Contains

```
column_name.Contains(search_parameter)
```

To select the 3 columns in linq just use this

```
.Select(x=> new { x.c1,x.c3,x.c3 })
```

And to get the top 50 just use

```
.Take(50)
```

So basically

```
var result = db.TableName.Where(x => x.column_name.Contains(search_parameter)).Select(x=> new { x.c1,x.c3,x.c3 }).Take(50);
```

**EDIT**

If you need to execute dynamic SQL you can use [SqlQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx)  something like this

```
string query = string.format("SELECT TOP 50 c1, c2, c3 
FROM TableName WHERE {0} LIKE '%{1}%'",column_name,search_parameter);
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<YOURRESULTCLASS>(query);
```

**EDIT 2**

If you have security concerns you can use a stored procedure instead

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<YOURRESULTCLASS>("storedProcedureName",params);
```

**EDIT 3**

Since the sample code is using [System.Linq.Dynamics](https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/) this code should work

```
string column_name = "name";
            string column_value = "C";
            string where = string.Format("{0}.Contains(@0)", column_name); //first create the where clause with the column name
            var result = Courses.Where(where,column_value).Select("new(name,courseID)").Take(50);   //here apply the column value to the name
```

This is the entire **console application** so you can test code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<course> Courses = new List<course>();
        Courses.Add(new course() { name = "CA", courseID = 1 });
        Courses.Add(new course() { name = "CB", courseID = 2 });
        Courses.Add(new course() { name = "CC", courseID = 3 });

        string column_name = "name";
        string column_value = "C";
        string where = string.Format("{0}.Contains(@0)", column_name); //first create the where clause with the column name
        var result = Courses.Where(where,column_value).Select("new(name,courseID)").Take(50);   //here apply the column value to the name
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class course
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int courseID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is not what the question is about. The "column_name" is not known at compile time.

Comment: From the question: "I am passing two strings(column name, search parameter) to my controller". This indicates that the column name is not known at compile time.

Comment: @VictorHugoTerceros i am trying to use Dynamic LINQ library(System.Linq.Dynamic) as i stated. Column name and search_parameters are unknown they are passed from front end via ajax. I am trying to avoid using SQLQuery.

Comment: @Wazner yes that is what i am asking for, got any idea?

Comment: @VictorHugoTerceros i tried using EDIT 3, but it gave me : A first chance exception of type 'System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException' occurred in System.Linq.Dynamic.dll
Error: Expression of type 'Boolean' expected. I am looking currently at stored procedures as last resort.

Comment: @fazic I edited my #3 now, I downloaded the library and tested this code, working perfectly, the problem is in your where clause, in your sample code you are using name and value as as linq variables, and the treat must be different, one is a value and the other is the name of the field

Comment: @VictorHugoTerceros This way it worked, thank you very much. Is this approach sql injection secured? Also for my other code i do not know what table name is similarly it is passed from front end(table_name).

Comment: @fazic good to know it worked, it is secure yes because it is still linq and does not allow sql injection, if my answer is correct please mark is as correct so we help more people who face this problem in the future

Comment: @VictorHugoTercerosok i marked you correct. NetMage 's anwser correct as well if for VS 2015 and newer if i am not wrong. But for my case since 2013 this approach works. Thanks again. Do you have any idea how i would solve the problem with dynamic table name?

Comment: it works for 2015 (I actually use it), yes i is possible, if you look at this code sample https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#DynamicLinq/DynamicLinq/Program.cs the exersice 2 has a "dynamic table", you can open a new question for that if needed.

Comment: Thank you. I will have to go through the example and understand it. If problems i'll start another question. Really appreciate the fast responses. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation isn't very clear, but I believe parameter substitution is only supported for values, not column names. While risky, you can use interpolation to insert the column names if you trust the source:

```
var result = db.TableName
   .Where($"{column_name}.Contains(@0)", search_parameter)
   .Select("new(c1, c2, c3)");
```

Comment: strange. If dynamic linq allows only manipulation of values at run time then there is no need for it since LINQ already allows for that. I thought it was possible to do something like: .Where("@0.Contain(@1)", columnname, search_parameter). Not sure why i can not reply to you by using @?

Comment: Well, the substitution for the column name in the string is manipulation at run time?

Comment: Yes if i understand your question correctly. I get column name based on the user's search option selection, which they select on front end. Controller does not know it till it is posted.

Comment: No, I meant that my shown code is manipulating setting the column name dynamically from the `column_name` variable by using string interpolation (C# 6), so I don't understand your issue with it.

Comment: Oh my bad misunderstood your there. The format you provide gives error expecting ';'. The Error comes the moment i add '$' sign before the quotes. The point i was making earlyer, it would be strange if Dynamic.LINQ does not support column substitution, since there is no point for it then. I can directly use LINQ to compare dynamic value to static(known) column name.

Comment: Ok it seems like string manipulation in that style is not supported in 2013 VS. I tried using string.Format as @VictorHugoTerceros linked. Store first in variable then pass. Basically same as what you recommended just more compatible with old VS 2013. Thank you.I will try to form full statement now see how it works. Also is this still secure or there is risk of SQL injection here?

Comment: Do you have any idea how i would deal with the problem of dynamic table name? Thank you.

Comment: There is definitely a risk of SQL injection. If you don't trust the source of the column name you should so some minimal validation such as blocking semi-colon and hyphen hyphen. You could also try putting square brackets around the column name and seeing if that will pass through to the SQL properly.

Comment: I see. The table column is selected from html.select attribute. So think it is trusted but to be safe i will filter it. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, I missed you question about @ - as the answer poster I am automatically notified of all comments on my answer, so an @ would be redundant.